# "How cool! /excellent!" in Latin

Tags: idiom, interjection

how is this current and wonder admiration spontaneous word externalized into *Romana lingua* ?

Sometimes, when my English knowledge is deficient, thus, I have the desire to write/communicate its expressions in Romana lingua

Comment: In some circles today people are using *macte!* or *mirabile!*. If it not merely cool or excellent but more surprising they might use *Papae!* / *Babae!* though I believe the later can be used also for bad news.

Answer (score 8):

[**Euge**](https://alatius.com/ls/index.php?met=up&ord=euge) is translated as “an exclamation of joy, applause, admiration, etc., *well done! good! bravo!*” You can also increase the emphasis by saying *euge euge* or *eugepae* (short for *euge papae*).

**Bene, perbene** and **optime** (or *optume*) are also common exclamations of joy or applause.

These are often combined, e.g.

- euge, optime!
- euge euge, perbene!

These are typical [Plautine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plautus) expressions. You won't catch Cicero saying *euge* or *papae* – but then, who could imagine Cicero saying “how cool” ;-)

Comment: It's interesting to consider that Plautus died ~80 years before Cicero was born. Do we know how much Latin colloquial usage might have shifted in that time?